# sendSubviewToBack is not working in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I want to adjust tableView's hierarchy. I used both `sendSubviewToBack` and `bringSubviewToFront` to make sure RedCell is under BlueCell, also I create the RedCell first so that BlueCell should beyond RedCell.(the overBgView in RedCell should not cover BlueCell) **However**, the result shows below, it's not working. So how to make sure the RedCell is under BlueCell?:
[image]
My code is here:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("<<< \(indexPath)")
        
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: RedCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! RedCell
            // RedCell
            tableView.sendSubviewToBack(cell)
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: BlueCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! BlueCell
            // BlueCell
            tableView.bringSubviewToFront(cell)
            return cell
        }
    }
    
    private lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        table.estimatedRowHeight = 80
        table.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        table.separatorStyle = .none
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        table.register(RedCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: RedCell.identifier)
        table.register(BlueCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: BlueCell.identifier)
        return table
    }()
    
    private lazy var label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "------split----the views below are not table cell"
        label.textColor = .black
        return label
    }()
    
    private lazy var view1: UIViewOne = {
        let view = UIViewOne()
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var view2: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        return view
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(RedCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "redCell")
        tableView.register(BlueCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "blueCell")
        setupUI()
    }
    
    public init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    private func setupUI() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        view.addSubview(label)
        view.addSubview(view1)
        view.addSubview(view2)
        
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(200)
            make.left.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(120)
        }
        
        label.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(tableView.snp.bottom).offset(30)
            make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(20)
        }
        
        view1.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(label.snp.bottom).offset(30)
            make.left.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(44)
        }
        view2.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(view1.snp.bottom)
            make.left.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(44)
        }
    }
}

class RedCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier = "RedCell"
    
    private lazy var overBgView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return view
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        backgroundColor = .red
        setupUI()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func setupUI() {
        contentView.addSubview(overBgView)
//        contentView.sendSubviewToBack(overBgView)
        self.superview?.sendSubviewToBack(overBgView)
        
        overBgView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.left.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(60)
        }
    }
}

class BlueCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier = "BlueCell"
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        backgroundColor = .blue
        setupUI()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func setupUI() {
        
    }
}

class UIViewOne: UIView {
    private lazy var oversizeView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return view
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .red
        addSubview(oversizeView)
        oversizeView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.left.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(60)
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Modifying the tableview view hierarchy is unlikely to work

Comment: In the actual request I received, there is a background image with the same top constraint as RedCell, but the height of this image is higher than RedCell, but at the same time it cannot cover the BlueCell below. So I hope to put this picture inside RedCell to achieve this effect. The final effect should be like the UIView below.

Comment: Can't you add the image view to the cell itself? Allow the image view to extend below the bottom of the cell but clip the image view to the cell.

Comment: I already add the imageView at the first cell, and allow it to expand. but it covered the second cell.

Comment: You have to ensure that you don't set a constraint between the bottom of the image view and the bottom of the cell. And make sure that `clipsToBounds` is set on the cell content view

Comment: yes I did not set bottom constraints. but if I set the clipsToBounds, the imageView will be cut off. I do not want it to be cut off, I want it to expand to next cell but not covered the next cell.

Comment: I don't know if you can achieve what you want

Comment: I figure it out that  tableview view hierarchy can be modified in table will display function.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is possible for you to modify tableView hierarchy at  willDisplay delegate function. Because in **func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)** the cell is not showed on screen, so it is useless to modify hierarchy in it. Just do like this, and it works:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            tableView.sendSubviewToBack(cell)
        } else {
            tableView.bringSubviewToFront(cell)
        }
    }
```

Then you can get the correct effect.
[image]